# Unable to read uninstall keys for x64 registry, vbscript

Tags: windows, vbscript, registry

I was trying to read the Uninstall Keys (DisplayName, Display Version, Vendor ..) from both 32 and 64 Bit installation keys. I have below code but it is always giving only 32 bit keys info. As I wrote the below code it is giving the entries from 32  bit twice :(

```
' Constants (taken from WinReg.h)
'
Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT   = &H80000000
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER   = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE  = &H80000002
Const HKEY_USERS          = &H80000003

Const REG_SZ        = 1
Const REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2
Const REG_BINARY    = 3
Const REG_DWORD     = 4
Const REG_MULTI_SZ  = 7

' Chose computer name, registry tree and key path
'

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Add

ObjExcel.Cells (1,1) = "Application Name"
ObjExcel.Cells (1,4) = "Application Vendor"
ObjExcel.Cells (1,2) = "Application Version"
ObjExcel.Cells (1,3) = "DRM Build"

strComputer = InputBox("Enter the Machine name. To run on the current machine, press ENTER", "Machine Name", "")
If strComputer = "" Then
    strComputer = "."
End If

Msgbox "Script is Running and may take couple of minutes to complete. Click on OK to continue",0, "Information"

hDefKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE


' Connect to registry provider on target machine with current user

Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

'{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!
' Enum the subkeys of the key path we've chosen

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

row = 2

getRegistryEntries hDefKey, strKeyPath, ObjExcel, oReg, row

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

getRegistryEntries hDefKey, strKeyPath, ObjExcel, oReg, row

fileName = Year(now) & month(now) & day(now) & hour(now) & minute(now) & second(now)

ObjExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\" & fileName & ".xlsx"
ObjExcel.Quit
Set ObjExcel = Nothing

msgbox "Work Done, file saved in C Drive with the name: " & fileName


Function getRegistryEntries(hDefKey, strKeyPath, byRef objExcel, byRef oReg, byRef row)

    oReg.EnumKey hDefKey, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys

    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


    For Each strSubkey In arrSubKeys

        ' Show the subkey
        '

        furtherKeys = False
        strDisName = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" & strKeyPath & "\" & strSubkey & "\DisplayName"

        On Error Resume Next

        present = False
        disName =  objShell.RegRead(strDisName)
        If disName <> "" Then
            present = True
        End If  

        disVersionPresent = false
        disVer = ""
        If present = true Then
            strDisVer = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" & strKeyPath & "\" & strSubkey & "\DisplayVersion"
            strDisVendor = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" & strKeyPath & "\" & strSubkey & "\Publisher"
            strDRMBuild = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" & strKeyPath & "\" & strSubkey & "\DRMBUILD"

            disVer = objShell.RegRead(strDisVer) 
            If  err.number = 0 Then
                disVersionPresent = True
            End If
            If disVersionPresent Then
                ObjExcel.Cells (row,1) = disName
                ObjExcel.Cells (row,2) = "'" & disVer
                furtherKeys = True
                disVendor = objShell.RegRead(strDisVendor) 
                If  err.number = 0 Then
                    ObjExcel.Cells (row,4) =  disVendor
                End If
                DRMBuild = objShell.RegRead(strDRMBuild) 
                If  err.number = 0 Then
                    ObjExcel.Cells (row,3) =  "'" & DRMBuild
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If furtherKeys Then
            row = row + 1
        End If
    Next


End Function
```

Comment: [tag:vbscript] <> [tag:vba] - Please remove the vba tag if it isn't about Visual Basic for Application.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running your script using `cscript.exe` (or `wscript.exe`) from the `C:\Windows\System32` directory and **not from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`**? Take a look in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open\Command`.

Comment: Woowww ... excellent, i was running by double clicking the file so far. Tried with cscript.exe and it worked :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, it worked but, facing the same problem when running on Remote Computer. Could you please help here...

Comment: And check the value from HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open\Command, and it is "%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*

Comment: oh my bad ... I got some clue, I am just doing wrong. I am trying to read the registry values with "disVer = objShell.RegRead(strDisVer)", but ah! this takes from the local machine, not on the remote machine, so I should be changing my logic to read the all keys and values with oReg  object only .... Thank you Josef for the tips and solution.